# Помогите найти ошибку в синтаксисе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите разобраться. При выполнении скрипта, ругается на не правильный синтаксис в месте двоеточия в строке **in S1_text_pdf:**. В интерпретаторе скрипт выполняется корректно. Лишних пробелов в указанном месте нету, переменные все существуют.

```
if 'Partial Basement' in S1_text_pdf:
 if S1_stories == '1': S1_basement['SqFt'] = str((int(S1_above_grade)-100)//2)
 else: S1_basement['SqFt'] = str((round(((int(S1_above_grade)-100)/(math.ceil(float(S1_stories))))//2)))
```

Comment: В данном коде нет синтаксических ошибок, отступы расставлены корректно, он будет работать при наличии нужных переменных. Давайте целиком скрипт, что ли

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, т.к. не указана конкретная ошибка, и проблема вообще оказалась в другой части кода.

Answer (score 2):

Подправил ответ, согласно комментарию, проверил код в вопросе, добавив переменные и нужный импорт:

```
import math

S1_text_pdf = ''
S1_stories = ''
S1_basement = dict()
S1_above_grade = 200

if 'Partial Basement' in S1_text_pdf:
 if S1_stories == '1': S1_basement['SqFt'] = str((int(S1_above_grade)-100)//2)
 else: S1_basement['SqFt'] = str((round(((int(S1_above_grade)-100)/(math.ceil(float(S1_stories))))//2)))
```

Comment: Тем не менее в вопросе отступы расставлены хоть и некрасиво, но корректно

Comment: @andreymal, что-то я поспешил, увидев тот код :)

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался, переменные были созданы, ругался именно на синтаксис функции, изначально код выглядел так.

```
if 'No Basement' in A1_text_pdf: 
A1_basement['SqFt']=A1_basement['Finished']='0'
if 'Crawl Space' in A1_text_pdf: 
A1_basement['SqFt']=A1_basement['Finished']='0'
else: 
 if 'Full Basement' in A1_text_pdf:
    if A1_stories == '1': A1_basement['SqFt'] = str(int(A_above_grade)-100)
    else: A1_basement['SqFt'] = str(round((int(A1_above_grade)-100)//int(A1_stories)))
 if 'Partial Basement' in A1_text_pdf:
    if A1_stories =='1': A1_basement['SqFt'] = str((int(A_above_grade)-100)//2)
    else: A1_basement['SqFt'] = str((round(((int(A1_above_grade)-100)/int(A1_stories))//2)))

if 'Finished All Basement' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['Finished'] = '100'
if 'Finished Partial Basement' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['Finished'] = '50'
if 'Unfinished Basement' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['Finished'] = '0'
```

Привел к такому виду и все заработало:

```
if 'Full Basement' in A1_text_pdf:
 if A1_stories == '1': A1_basement['SqFt'] = str(int(A1_above_grade)-100)
 else: A1_basement['SqFt'] = str(round((int(A1_above_grade)-100)//(math.ceil(float(A1_stories)))))

if 'Partial Basement' in A1_text_pdf: 
 if A1_stories == '1': A1_basement['SqFt'] = str((int(A1_above_grade)-100)//2)
 else: A1_basement['SqFt'] = str((round(((int(A1_above_grade)-100)/(math.ceil(float(A1_stories))))//2)))

if 'Finished All Basement' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['Finished'] = '100'
if 'Finished Partial Basement' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['Finished'] = '50'
if 'Unfinished Basement' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['Finished'] = '0'
if 'No Basement' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['SqFt']=A1_basement['Finished']='0'
if 'Basement None' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['SqFt']=A1_basement['Finished']='0'
if 'Crawl Space' in A1_text_pdf: A1_basement['SqFt']=A1_basement['Finished']='0'
```

Comment: Жесть. Я бы посоветовал ознакомиться с [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) ([перевод](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)) и стараться ему следовать хотя бы в плане отступов.

Comment: До воли сложно применять его к редактору текста сайта который отступы сам по себе нормально не выделяет )

Comment: используйте другой редактор)